# Repositioning Items In ASP.NET ListView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, listview, sql-order-by

I have a `ListView control` on my ASP.NET web form.

It is populated with a simple `SELECT from SQL data source`. One of the items returned by SELECT has a value "All".

> I want that item to be the first item of the ListView.

I tried setting `DisplayIndex` and `DataItemIndex` to `0`, but these properties are `read-only`. ORDER BY does not always work either. 
Could someone please provide a solution in *c# or SQL*? Thank you.

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ListName" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="ListNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ListName") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ListName] FROM [Lists]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Can you post the query ? Also if possbile post some code to let us imagine what is happening

Comment: Please share some code

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I designed an ugly solution for it. SELECT statement should look like this:
`SELECT [ListName] FROM [Lists] WHERE [ListName] = 'All' UNION SELECT [ListName] FROM [Lists] WHERE [ListName] != 'All'`